# How to move the list entries to the a new dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
contact = {
"tom":"081908632739",
"Jhon" : "081608976523",
"Dean" : "081308976542"
}

number = ['081108760091', '081308111897', '081908631243']
new_contact = {}
for who in contact:
for i in range(len(number)):
new_contact[who] = number[i]
print(new_contact)
```

the output show every people in contact has a same number in list of number with the last index

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what's the *problem*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is the nested loops. These two lines:

```py
for who in contact:
   for i in range(len(number)):
```

On the last iteration, it's setting the last value in the list to all contacts. You should use a python visualizer to understand what's going on, see [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

You can change it to the following, using a simple counter variable that increments on each iteration.

```py
contact = {
"tom":"081908632739",
"Jhon" : "081608976523",
"Dean" : "081308976542"
}

number = ['081108760091', '081308111897', '081908631243']
new_contact = {}
counter = 0
for who in contact:
        new_contact[who] = number[counter]
        counter+=1
print(new_contact)
```

Output:

`{'tom': '081108760091', 'Jhon': '081308111897', 'Dean': '081908631243'}`